# How to proceed to develop a simple app that posts the link on users wall on like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

I basically want to know where should I start reading to develop such a simple thing. What I need is When someone clicks on like the link of that page is automatically put on the persons' wall. Now I researched a bit and found many tutorials, but mostly the deprecated ones. I know how to code in php and all the requisites. Just need to know where to learn to do this little thing.

Comment: The like button will be on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and then it would be a copy, paste stuff for you !